# Objects as properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I'm defining a javascript object and setting its properties and methods like this:

```
function MyObject()
{
  this.prop1 = 1;
  this.prop2 = 2;

  this.meth1=meth1;
}

function meth1()
{
  // do soemthing
}
```

All is fine. My question is how can i have an object be a property of MyObject? I actually want an 'associative array' as a property something along these lines:

```
function MyObject()
{
  this.obj['x'] = 'val1';
  this.obj['y'= = 'val2';

  this.prop1 = 1;
  this.prop2 = 2;

  this.meth1=meth1;
}
```

I have tried declaring obj in MyObject like this: `obj = new Object`; with no luck, obj is not being interpreted as a property.

Any clues as to what i'm doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.obj = {'x': 'val1', 'y': 'val2'};

  this.prop1 = 1;
  this.prop2 = 2;

  this.meth1=meth1;
}
```

?

Now you can say:

```
new MyObject().obj.x  //`val1`
```

Alternative syntax:

```
this.obj = {};
this.obj.x = 'val1';
this.obj.y = 'val2';
```

Comment: Yup. it works. Thanks Tomasz for the answer. I thought `this.obj['x'] = 'val1';` and `this.obj = {'x': 'val1', 'y': 'val2'};` were equivalent! what's the difference?

Comment: djeetee, don't forget to up-vote and select this answer as the correct one if it solved your problem.

Comment: *@djeetee*: they are equivalent in most cases. Square-bracket syntax can be used when you need an identifier that is a JavaScript keyword like: `obj['var']` - `obj.var` or `obj.'var'` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's often easiest to use the object literal notation:

```
function MyObject()
{
  // obj as an object literal
  this.obj = {
     x: "val1",
     y: "val2",
     z: "val3"
  };

  this.prop1 = 1;
  this.prop2 = 2;

  this.meth1=meth1;
}
```